# How can I solve the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute author" and change the NoneType so my code can work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I integrated slash commands for my bot but I seem to have issues with /taskdone and /viewtasks command working properly. Whenever I try to use them, I just get the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'"
or
"discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'taskdone' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'"

I can't figure out how to fix this error and make the code run properly. The code version without the slash commands works fine, so I probably implemented something incorrectly in the slash command version.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import json
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    synced = await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f'Synced {len(synced)} command(s)')


@bot.tree.command(name='help', description='Displays a list of all available commands.')
async def help(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    help_embed = discord.Embed(title='Commands',
                               description='``!help``\n**Displays this help message.**\n\n``!taskdone``\n **Adds +1 to your amount of completed tasks.**\n\n``!viewtasks``\n**Displays a list of every developer and their number of completed tasks.**',
                               color=0x2f3136)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=help_embed)


@bot.tree.command(name='ping', description= 'Shows latency.')
async def ping(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'**Latency:** {bot.latency} Milliseconds')


@bot.tree.command(name='taskdone', description ='Adds +1 to your amount of completed tasks.')
async def taskdone(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    authorID = str(interaction.message.author.id)
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        juniorDevs = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Junior Developers')
        seniorDevs = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Senior Developers')
        leadDevs = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Lead Developers')
        projectManagers = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Project Managers")

        if juniorDevs in interaction.message.author.roles or seniorDevs in interaction.message.author.roles or leadDevs in interaction.message.author.roles or projectManagers in interaction.message.author.roles:
            with open('database.json', 'r') as f:
                data = json.load(f)

            if authorID in data.keys():
                data[authorID] += 1

                with open('database.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

            elif authorID not in data.keys():
                data[authorID] = 1

                with open('database.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)

            await interaction.response.send_message('**Task amount updated!** :white_check_mark:')
        elif juniorDevs not in interaction.message.author.roles or seniorDevs not in interaction.message.author.roles or leadDevs not in interaction.message.author.roles or projectManagers not in interaction.message.author.roles:
            await interaction.response.send_message('**You do not have permission to run this command!** :x:')

@bot.tree.command(name='viewtasks', description = 'Displays a list of every developer and their number of completed tasks.')
async def viewtasks(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        juniorDevs = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Junior Developers')
        seniorDevs = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Senior Developers')
        leadDevs = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Lead Developers')
        projectManagers = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Project Managers")

        # Open the database file in read mode
        with open('database.json', 'r') as database:
            # Load the contents of the file into a dictionary
            data = json.load(database)

        if juniorDevs in interaction.message.author.roles or seniorDevs in interaction.message.author.roles or leadDevs in interaction.message.author.roles or projectManagers in interaction.message.author.roles:
            # Initialize the message
            message_text = ""
            # Build the message using string formatting
            for user_id, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
                message_text += f"<@{user_id}>**: {value}**\n"

            # Create the embed
            task_embed = discord.Embed(title='Tasks Completed This Week', description=message_text, color=0x2f3136)

            # Send the embed
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=task_embed)

        elif juniorDevs not in interaction.message.author.roles or seniorDevs not in interaction.message.author.roles or leadDevs not in interaction.message.author.roles or projectManagers not in interaction.message.author.roles:
            # The message author does not have one of the roles
            #Don't perform the code actions
            await interaction.response.send_message('**You do not have permission to run this command!** :x:')


def reset_values():
    # Open the database file in read mode
    with open('database.json', 'r') as f:
        # Load the contents of the file into a dictionary
        data = json.load(f)

    # Iterate through the keys in the dictionary
    for key in data.keys():
        # Set the value of each key to 0
        data[key] = 0

    # Open the file in write mode
    with open('database.json', 'w') as f:
        # Write the updated dictionary to the file
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# Schedule the reset_values function to run every Monday at 00:00
scheduler.add_job(reset_values, 'cron', day_of_week='1', hour=0, minute=0)

scheduler.start()
# non-slash command part of code
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = str(message.content).lower().split(' ')
    if args[0] == 'bruh':
        await message.channel.send('<:bruh_stone:1059119664543825950>')

    elif args[0] == "i'm" and " ".join(args[1:]) == "horny":
        await message.channel.send('https://tenor.com/view/vorzek-vorzneck-oglg-og-lol-gang-gif-24901093')

    elif args[0] == "im" and " ".join(args[1:]) == "horny":
        await message.channel.send('https://tenor.com/view/vorzek-vorzneck-oglg-og-lol-gang-gif-24901093')


bot.run('token')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't show your code we can't tell you what's wrong...

Comment: Code has been provided.

Comment: There are no slash commands here, so I don't see how you'd expect them to work. Also, if you want commands without prefix, just set the prefix to an empty string (`""`) so you can use the `Commands` framework instead of all this string parsing.

Comment: Alright, I got the slash commands to work as well as non slash ones. Right now I'm just struggling to fix the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author' error for 2 of my commands. Could you please look into it and let me know if you have a possible solution in mind?

Comment: If you don't include the entire traceback in your post then no I can't look into it because I can't know what or where the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a few days ago.
Instead of:

```
authorID = str(interaction.message.author.id)
```

you're supposed to use:

```
 authorID = str(interaction.user.id)
```

And to fix the rest of the code simply change every instance of:

```
interaction.message.author.roles
```

to:

```
interaction.user.roles
```

There is no message to get the author ID from since slash commands are used, hence the attribute error. Simply changing every instance that asked for the author and message attribute with user attribute fixed the problem.